# Google tag manager error when loading resource from url for Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to add GTM through Android studio 3.0.1 The container is publish yet the container is not getting loaded.
I am getting an error

```
 E/GoogleTagManager: NetworkLoader: Error when loading resource from url:
https://www.google-analytics.com/gtm/android?id=GTM-XXXXXXX&pv=-1&rv=5.0
    Bad response: 403
```

Comment: I am also getting the same error any solution for this ?